# I can't activate logging with Log4Net on .Net 5, Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, log4net

I made an Asp Net.Core project that can run database query, but when I try to log operations to the database and a .json file, it works normally without logging to these places. How can I fix this problem? Is there any point I've missed out on? Or it is about the difference of .Net Core between .Net? Thanks in advance. Here is my config file and LogAspect class:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="JsonFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="/Users/user/Log//log.json" />
      <layout type="DevFramework.Core2.CrossCuttingConcerns.Logging.Log4Net.Layouts.JsonLayout" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="SqlServerAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="Data Source= ***;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID= sa; Password=***" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Logs ([Detail],[Date1],[Audit1]) VALUES (@logDetail,@log_date,@audit)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logDetail" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="DevFramework.Core2.CrossCuttingConcerns.Logging.Log4Net.Layouts.JsonLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{dd'-'MM'-'yyyy' yyyy':'mm':'ss'.'fff}" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@audit" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <logger name="JsonFileLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="JsonFileAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="DatabaseLogger">
      <level value="All" />
      <appender-ref ref="SqlServerAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

**-----------------------------**

```
namespace DevFramework.Core2.Aspects.PostSharp.LogAspects
{
    [PSerializable]
    [MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method, TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Instance)]
    public class LogAspect:OnMethodBoundaryAspect
    {
        private Type _loggerType;
        private LoggerService _loggerService;
        public LogAspect(Type loggerType)
        {
            _loggerType = loggerType;
        }

        public override void RuntimeInitialize(MethodBase method)
        {
            if(_loggerType.BaseType!=typeof(LoggerService))
            {
                throw new Exception("Wrong Logger Type");
            }

            _loggerService = (LoggerService)Activator.CreateInstance(_loggerType);
            base.RuntimeInitialize(method);
        }

        public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            if (!_loggerService.IsInfoEnabled)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                var logParameters = args.Method.GetParameters().Select((t, i) => new LogParameter
                {
                    Name = t.Name,
                    Type = t.ParameterType.Name,
                    Value = args.Arguments.GetArgument(i)
                }).ToList();

                var logDetail = new LogDetail
                {
                    FullName = args.Method.DeclaringType == null ? null : args.Method.DeclaringType.Name,
                    MethodName = args.Method.Name,
                    Parameters = logParameters
                };

                _loggerService.Info(logDetail);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Is there any point I've missed out on?` Probably - but without seeing your code it's impossible to say. At a minimum, please edit your question to include the code that sets up the logging, and the code that does the logging, and any relevant configuration and error messages. But broadly, log4net works just fine with .NET core, so it's likely just how you have it configured.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit.

Comment: Is that a `web.config` or `log4net.config`? If it's a `log4net.config` can you post the code where you are calling `XmlConfigurator.Configure` or equivalent? I notice you are also using PostSharp - that's a whole extra level of complication, so I would suggest you first of all ensure that the log4net is configured and working correctly and then raise a separate question for PostSharp once you know log4net is working fine (i.e. by logging from inside a controller method or something)

Comment: (Finally, I note that you are silently suppressing exceptions inside your `OnEntry` method - try writing to the console or somewhere you will actually see any exceptions here as silently throwing away exceptions is almost never a good idea)

Comment: It is log4net.config, and I used PostSharp aspects in more than one place. I am a learner that doesn't know to code well, even hasn't added XmlConfigurator.Configure. I had seen another question but didn't understand completely. Thanks, I will research more.